# How to choose npm over yarn in vue create

Tags: vue.js, npm, yarnpkg

I want to create a Vue project, and I want to use `npm`.

In the terminal, when I do `vue create hello`, by default `yarn` is used as a package manager.

So how to start straight with `npm` instead of `yarn`?

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply type `vue create --help` to find out which options the vue create command offers.

```
vue create hello --packageManager npm
```

is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can either choos the `--packageManager` commandline option or check the default packagemanager, which is saved under `~/.vuerc` (the user home directory)

Answer (score 0):

You can see your Vue config with
`vue config`

```
 {
  "useTaobaoRegistry": false,
  "packageManager": "yarn"
}
```

You can edit your Vue config object with :
`vue config -s <KEY> <VALUE>`

So, for setup npm as default Package manager for Vue :
`vue config -s packageManager npm`

More Vue config:
`vue config -h`